# Как сделать все предупреждения tslint ошибками в typescript в vscode?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, configuration, tslint

**Обновление 2**
Output для картинки 2 из обновления 1 начинался так:http://prntscr.com/gchos2

> [Info  - 15:51:37] vscode-tslint: 'Cannot read property 'prototype' of
>   undefined' while validating:
>   d:\dev\Lyles\lyles\Pnp\Web\Lyles.Pnp.Web\src\polyfills.browser.ts
>   stacktrace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Возможно проблема в vscode-lint?

**Обновление 1**

Обновил версию tslint до последней. 5.6.0

перезагрузил vscode - на картинке 1 никаких ошибок. Окно output получил, нажав на tslint: error.

Картинка 1 - http://prntscr.com/gchf9k

Добавляем лишнюю пустую строку. На картинке 2 видно, что tslint как-то отработал, только почему-то vscode теперь вообще не подчёркивает такие ошибки. Проект естественно запускается.

Картинка 2 - http://prntscr.com/gchidg

**Оригинальный вопрос**

Ниже моя конфигурация для tslint.json. При такой конфигурации, например, отсутствие ; или лишний пробел трактуются как warning - подчёривает зелёным и даёт собирать проект. Как сделать, чтобы все warning, tslint трактовал как ошибки. проект на Ангуляр 2+, без angular-cli. Редактор - vscode.

```
  {
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "trailing-comma": [
      false,
      {
        "multiline": "always",
        "singleline": "never"
      }
    ],
    "interface-name": [
      false,
      "always-prefix"
    ],
  }
```

Comment: что за код вставлен в вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy tslint.json

Comment: а собираешь чем?

Comment: @Grundy tslint cli

Comment: @Grundy если о проекте, то webpack + package.json

Comment: покажи настройку tslint в webpack, или ты его только вручную запускаешь?

Comment: @Grundy package.json, в webpack ничего ему не настриваю "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",